# Is しごと pronounced as 'shingocto'?

Tags: words, phonology

I downloaded Genki and the CDs that came with it. しごと was pronounced as 'shingocto' instead of 'shigoto.' Why is that?

Comment: Is your native language English? Japanese "g" does occasionally sound like ng, but I don't understand where you're getting "gocto"; there shouldn't be a "c" sound anywhere in there.

Comment: It was probably pronounced wrong in the cd. So is it pronounced "Shingoto" then?

Comment: Some dialects of Japanese (particularly common ones) have a nasal g sound. It's not しんごと though.

Comment: Read here for the "proper" pronunciation of 「ご」: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/the-nasal-allophones-of-g/26238#26238

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The nasal allophones of /g/](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/the-nasal-allophones-of-g)

Answer (score -1):

I am not native, but when I have spoken with Japanese or even watched TV / movies I have never heard 仕事{しごと} any way but as しごと

Feel free to find other sources of audio (actually do!)

I found a [great video that start off with 仕事](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRa-Yf2JWfI)

To my ears, his accent (if he has one) is spot on. Although a native speaker is a much better judge of that.

Comment: 鼻濁音を正しく発音してるアナウンサーのビデオとか持ってきてくんないとあんま参考には・・・