# How to pronounce ぎ?

Tags: pronunciation

So far, I've met it only in [右](http://jisho.org/search/migi) and [一本気](http://jisho.org/search/ippongi). In the former ぎ sounds like "ni". In the letter, it sounds like "ni" probably, but I seem to hear "g" sound in it as well, if I'm not imagining it.

Is there indeed "g" sounds there? If so, I'd appreciate it if you try and explain how to pronounce it.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11832/1478 or http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4708/1478

Comment: Also see: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26227/1478 (missed this one!)

Comment: Some people use voiced fricative [ɣ] in the place where [ŋ] would appear (like the female voice who pronounces 右側 in your link).

Answer (score 0):

I might not fully understand the question (you kind of made it a bit confusing:), but き with dakuten (these two small dashes on the right side of き) will always make ぎ(gi). I have japanese lessons with native speakers and there was never anything else than ぎ(gi).

Comment: You can follow the links I provided and check out how it sounds on jisho.org.

Comment: 「[鼻濁音]{びだくおん}」を調べてみてください

Comment: Or watch some Youtube videos.  This one is in Japanese, but it looks very authoritative.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amscTH7z3iM