# Pronunciation of /g/

Tags: pronunciation

I have heard the following sentence in an audio file of a dialogue in the Japanese language teaching book Genki (vol 1):

はがきは イギリスまでいくらですか？ (= How much is a postcard to the UK? )

There is a clear N sound in the syllable が of はがき and I hardly hear any G. It seems to me that the speaker is pronouncing が as [na] or [ŋa] instead of [ga] (IPA syntax). Is that an accent? If so, from where?

Comment: I think this has been answered in detail here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/177/pronouncing-%e3%81%8c-as-nga/21423#21423 and here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/why-does-the-g-tends-to-sound-more-like-a-m-or-n/62878#62878

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/the-nasal-allophones-of-g

It's apparently considered a little more 'proper' to use the nasal version in applicable situations.