# Pronouncing ichigo

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

I would like to know how ichigo is pronounced. I have listened but I cannot catch it. I would love to understand the rules for this pronunciation.

Comment: Have you tried: https://forvo.com/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1%E3%81%94%2C_%E3%82%A4%E3%83%81%E3%82%B4%2C_%E8%8B%BA/#ja　If you're struggling with the nasal /g/ sound, these posts might help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11832/9831 ・  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/26238/9831

Comment: I think this is one of those rare times where saying "watch some anime" is a legitimate suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pronounced as it's spelled. 
I-chi-go .