# What does he exactly say in this phrase?

Tags: translation

I know the title of the topic is really bad because it isn't descriptive, but I don't know how to phrase it really. If you have a better idea please edit it.

What does Yamcha say in this phrase? What I hear is

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Af-IL6K34po&t=170s

"Sora na kirei da na" but this doesn't make sense to me, it seems syntactically wrong, I believe for saying "the sky is pretty" it would be something like "sora wa kirei da" or perhaps "sora wa kirei da na" but not what I hear. What is he exactly saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He says, 「そら**が**きれいだな」.

[が can be pronounced as "nga"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/177/9749), which can sound like な if you're not used to the difference.

Comment: the particle at the end "na" is supposed to be similar to "ne", that usually is used for confirmation from other person in a dialogue, isnt it? But he's talking to himself, what connotation does it add here?

Comment: @Pablo Although na can be used like ne for confirmation with the proper intonation, it mostly used as some-kind of observational mark. It can be used even when talking to yourself.(talking to yourself is always weird, but it's a manga so...). It's hard to translate its meaning, but it would be something like "wow, the sky really is beautiful". You can even sometime use "dayona" too.