# What is pimsleur saying (shtain desnoga)?

Tags: pronunciation, particle-の, phonetics, listening

Listening to the first Pimsleur Japanese audiobook and I'm having a hard time recognizing the words its saying. It says to say "I want to go shopping" and then in Japanese says something that sounds like "kaimonoga shtain desnoga". What are the actual words it's saying?

My best guess after reading some posts is that it's saying shitai desu ga. Are the n sounds just a regional accent? Or do they change the meaning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a0-etc)

Comment: I have a hunch that this might be related to: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/the-nasal-allophones-of-g/26238#26238

Comment: The `/n/` on the end of `shtain` is ん as a spoken contraction of の.  Parse the whole thing as したい・の・です・が.

Comment: So the が(ga) sounds like んが(nga) or のが(noga) to your ear, right? Then I'd recommend you look up "nasal /g/" or 「[鼻濁音]{びだくおん}」. This thread might also be some help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/177/9831

Answer (score 2):

The sentence was simply

> [買]{か}い[物]{もの}がしたいん/のですが
>
> > Kaimono ga shitai -n/no desu ga

which is saying that the speaker explains that he/she wants to go shopping.

There's no particular accent here.

Comment: `買い物したいんですが` ←そうかもしれませんけど、録音されてるのは「買い物**が**したいんですが」かもね・・・