# Why words having 'が' in between other letters pronounced as 'んが'？

Tags: pronunciation

I came across many cases where I found Japanese natives pronouncing some words containing `が` or `ぎ` letter with others (Example: `かぎ`, `ちがいます`) as `んが` or `んぎ`.

Are there any rules to do this in any particular context or something?

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/177/5010 and  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54535/5010